# Google Chrome Android Commas in numeric Input (Bootstrap-Vue)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, bootstrap-vue, html-input

First of all: This issue does not occur on any other browser, except Google Chrome for Android (90.0.4430.210).

We have an input that looks like this. Only numerics should be entered. Our Input looks something like this.

[image]

```html
<b-form-input
  v-model="manualInput"       
  class="text-center text-primary bold font-weight-bold"     
  id="manInput"
  type="number"
  inputMode="numeric"
  pattern="[0-9]*"
  min="1"
  max="20"
  @keypress="checkValidation($event)"
  @keyup="checkValidation($event)"
  @mouseup="checkValidation($event)"
  @paste="onPaste($event)"
/>
```

(The "onPaste" event is not important, it basically prevents the user from pasting any content)

```js
private checkValidation(evt) {
  console.log(this.manualInput);

  //Check if there is an input
  if (this.manualInput.length) {
    //At least one number
    var stamps: number = +this.manualInput;
    //Check if the input is valid (just in case)
    if (stamps < this.min || stamps > this.max || !this.manualInput.match("[0-9]{1,3}")) {
      //Input is invalid
      this.showAlert = true;
      this.isValid = false;
    } else {
      //Input is valid
      this.showAlert = false;
      this.isValid = true;
    }
  } else {
    //No content
    this.showAlert = false;
    this.isValid = false;
  } 
}
```

As I already said, this works perfectly on all desktop browsers, firefox (mobile) and safari (mobile). But on android, it is possible to enter commas and dots!

[image]

Now for the weird part: I tried to replace the commas and dots with `this.manualInput.replace(".", "").replace(",", "")` in the first line of the function. BUT, the input string is still empty, when you enter just a comma. When I print the string in the console, it prints an empty string, even though I entered a comma. As soon as I enter a number, the comma appears in the console. This is obviously bad for the user, since it appears, that he can enter a comma. I would be very glad if somebody knows why this happens and how I can prevent it.

Comment: You should rather probably use the `formatter` prop on `b-form-input` to define a specific format: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-input#comp-ref-b-form-input-props

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `formatter` as shown here: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-input#formatter-support

```html
<b-form-input
  id="input-formatter"
  v-model="text1"
  placeholder="Enter your name"
  :formatter="formatter"
></b-form-input>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        text1: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      formatter(value) {
        return value.split(/ /)[0].replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The regex was taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3097076/8816585

Comment: Hello! Sorry for my late answer, I was incredibly busy. This still does not work. It works on desktop devices, but not on mobile. It's kinda hard to describe, but it is still possible to enter `2.`, but the number at least corrects itself, as soon as I enter the next digit `2.` -> `2.4` -> `24`. Sadly this still does not fix the problem I have, since it is still possible to input commas and dots.

Comment: If `<b-form-input>` is an input behind the scene, you should write `inputMode` as `inputmode`. Not sure if this typo breaks the whole thing. Also check this one, is it working as you'd expect on iOS: https://codesandbox.io/embed/ios-force-numeric-keypad-on-input-typenumber-demo-41dkz?view=preview&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&fontsize=14 ?

Comment: I honestly couldn't test it on an iOS device yet (since I do not have one currently). The typo does not make any difference. Mobile Chrome opens the correct "numpad" keyboard. It is literally only possible to enter the numbers 0-9 and the comma/dot. For me it looks like the number is buffered when I enter a decimal and then flushed, as soon as it gets valid again (if I add a number after the period, or remove the period). Therefore the validator does not get called during the buffered timeframe. I can't find anything online regarding this assumption.

Comment: Yep, it is "flushed" because the regex validates the whole string and strips the useless part. So, it's a matter of post-input here. Not sure if there is a way to directly prevent the input with HTML but you could watch the pressed key as here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-cancel-a-keypress/5922/2